# Logout of tty but save session for next login

Tags: arch-linux, x11, tty, session, sleep

5.18.9-arch1-1
Dell XPS 15 9510

I am running arch linux on xmonad. I do not have a login manager. On boot, I simply login via the tty and run startx to start my x session. This behavior is exactly what I want.

However, when I sleep or hibernate via systemctl sleep/hibernate, upon waking I am thrown right back into my graphical environment. I find this behavior to be insecure because I do not have to reauthenticate. I would like to be able to sleep/hibernate, relogin to my tty, then be put right back into my graphical environment with the state preserved.

I feel as though this must be something that a lot of people would want to do yet I cannot seem to find any resources on how to do it. I would prefer to continue to not have a login manager and only interface with the tty for authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this from a start-up script.

With the i3 window manager, you can execute a shell script from the i3 config to execute programs and move them to the appropriate workspace.

There are a few other ways to run scripts on startup, e.g. cron, rc.local, init.d.
Source: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/run-script-on-startup

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I sleep or hibernate via systemctl sleep/hibernate, upon
> waking I am thrown right back into my graphical environment. I find
> this behavior to be insecure because I do not have to reauthenticate.

Create a hook on sleep/hibernate/resume to launch an external screen locker is simpler and keeps your session and your work alive.